# inheriting log4j Logger

Tags: java, log4j

I'm planning to replace old logger with log4j one. Instead of using Logger directly I need to create new class LocalLogger inherited of Logger. Reason of doing that - I need new logging method names that was available in old logger.

I have log4j logger:

```
protected final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());
```

How to make function that could make LocalLogger in the same way like Logger does?

How to pass class c to super LocalLogger?

Draft for the LocalLogger:

```
public class LocalLogger extends Logger{

    protected LocalLogger(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public LocalLogger getLocalLogger(Class c)
    {
        return new LocalLoger(???)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you don't extend `Logger` in this instance. Instead, use the [delegation pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern).

Create a brand new class with the methods you wish to have, but delegate the logging calls to an internal instance of `Logger`:

```
public class LocalLogger {

  private final Logger logger;

  public LocalLogger(String name) {
    logger = Logger.getLogger(name);
  }

  public LocalLogger(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Class clazz) {
    logger = Logger.getLogger(clazz);
  }

  public void antiqueLoggingMethod(String msg) {
    logger.info(msg);
  }

  // etc.
}
```